# Kafka S3 Source Connector for PARQUET format in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, parquet, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have topic events being produced using Protobuf. I could successfully sink my topic events into an S3 bucket using the S3 Sink connector in Parquet format. Now I have in my S3 bucket objects of type `.parquet` and `.key.parquet`. All this worked as expected using the following configuration:

```
{
    "name": "s3-sink",
    "config": {
      "name": "s3-sink",
      "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
      "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
      "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.parquet.ParquetFormat",
      "keys.format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.parquet.ParquetFormat",
      "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
      "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter",
      "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://my-schema-registry",
      "value.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO",
      "value.converter.basic.auth.user.info": "MY_SR_API_KEY:MY_SR_API_SECRET",
      "store.kafka.keys": true,
      "parquet.codec": "none",
      "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.HourlyPartitioner",
      "locale": "en-US",
      "s3.bucket.name": "my-bucket-123",
      "s3.region": "eu-west-1",
      "time.interval": "HOURLY",
      "flush.size": 1000,
      "tasks.max": 1,
      "topics.regex": "test-topic.*",
      "confluent.license": "",
      "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "my-bootstrap-server",
      "confluent.topic.replication.factor": 3,
      "confluent.license.topic.replication.factor": 1,
      "confluent.topic.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
      "confluent.topic.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"MY_API_KEY\" password=\"MY_API_SECRET\";",
      "confluent.topic.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
      "confluent.topic.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm": "https"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to put back my keys and values in `my-bucket-123` (`parquet` format) into a Kafka topic using Protobuf. For that, I set up a new S3 Source Connector (`confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3-source:1.4.5`) by Confluent using the following configuration:

```
{
    "name": "s3-source",
    "config": {
      "name": "s3-source",
      "dest.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "my-bootstrap-server",
      "dest.topic.replication.factor": 1,
      "dest.kafka.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
      "dest.kafka.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
      "dest.kafka.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"MY_API_KEY\" password=\"MY_API_SECRET\";",
      "tasks.max": 1,
      "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnector",
      "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.parquet.ParquetFormat",
      "confluent.license": "",
      "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "my-bootstrap-server",
      "confluent.topic.replication.factor": 3,
      "confluent.license.topic.replication.factor": 1,
      "confluent.topic.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
      "confluent.topic.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"MY_API_KEY\" password=\"MY_API_SECRET\";",
      "confluent.topic.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
      "confluent.topic.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm": "https",
      "transforms": "AddPrefix",
      "transforms.AddPrefix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
      "transforms.AddPrefix.regex": ".*",
      "transforms.AddPrefix.replacement": "copy_of_$0",
      "s3.region": "eu-west-1",
      "s3.bucket.name": "my-bucket-123"
    }
}
```

By using above configuration I cannot start my S3 source connector. If I validate the configuration using above configuration and the command:

```
curl -X PUT -d @config.json --header "content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connector-plugins/S3SourceConnector/config/validate
```

I get the following error in the `format.class` property:

```
"errors":[
               "Invalid value io.confluent.connect.s3.format.parquet.ParquetFormat for configuration format.class: Class io.confluent.connect.s3.format.parquet.ParquetFormat could not be found.",
               "Invalid value null for configuration format.class: Class must extend: io.confluent.connect.cloud.storage.source.StorageObjectFormat"
            ]
```

I am starting to think that this S3 source connector does not support `Parquet` format. I tried to validate it against JSON, AVRO and BYTE formats and all of them are okay.

Digging into the S3 Source connector jar files (`1.4.5`), I did not find one for Parquet format:

[Formats in Jar files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tArK.png)

Anyone has an idea what is going on here? Is there any other way to put data back from S3 - Parquet format into my Kafka cluster?

Thanks!

Comment: The S3 connectors are primarily meant for analysis, not backup/restore. That being said, Parquet is a columnar format, so cannot be easily read to individual records like row-based Avro/JSON/text-lines can

Comment: Hey. Did you get any progress with it? @crileroro

Comment: No progress @kalosh. The source connector does not support Parquet format (At least last time I saw it one year ago. Not sure if something has changed since then)

Answer (score 0):

From the Confluent's S3 Source Connector documentation:

> Out of the box, the connector supports reading data from S3 in Avro and JSON format. Besides records with schema, the connector supports importing plain JSON records without schema in text files, one record per line. In general, the connector may accept any format that provides an implementation of the Format interface.

So it means you should be able to add/plugin of implementation of the `parquet` format, but it is not built in out of the box

Source code for the format:

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/blob/master/kafka-connect-s3/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/s3/format/parquet/ParquetFormat.java

Comment: There's tools to take Parquet to Avro. Not sure that really helps get the data back to Protobuf, like it seems OP wants

Comment: OP showing error that reading parquet is failing on class not found... the reading format are pluggable, he might need to have a setting for a value converters as well to get it to PROTOBUFF

Comment: Sure, but you linked to a `Format` interface for the Sink, not `io.confluent.connect.cloud.storage.source.StorageObjectFormat` needed for the source

Comment: `. In general, the connector may accept any format that provides an implementation of the Format interface.` <- from the official documentation

Comment: Assuming the sink and source are the same Connect cluster, why wouldn't it work, then?

Comment: It is in diffrent connector plugin libraries? It is stand alone connectors? Don't know OP deployment... It might need to be fixed to support the source, but I believe it is a starting point..

Comment: He is using rest so its distributed connect deployment